# Making custom tr.c function

Tags: c, io, tr

```
void tr_str(char s[], char news[]){
int c;
size_t k =0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        for(k=0; k < strlen(s);k++)
        {                   
            if(c == s[k])
            {
                c = news[k];
            }
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

This is my translate function that currently takes in two arguments from command line and uses those letters to switch the first set to second set. I just found an issue where it doesnt work if the two arguments are different length. What has to happen is if 1st argument is 3 char length and second is 2 char length, the second argument gets a 3rd char added to it and it should be equal to the last char stored in it. Ex: arg1(a,b,c); arg2(x,y); When used arg2 becomes arg2(x,y,y);

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at `strstr()`, `strchr()`, `strspn()`?

Comment: None of these functions is ideal, since you really want a function that is `size_t indexof(char *haystack, int needle)`, but the best you get is `char *strchr(char *haystack, int needle)`, so you need to calculate the index by subtacting pointers.

Comment: I sort of get what you are talking about. The amount of pointers shows how many actual values are stored in the array correct? Using that I guess I can make a loop to fill the leftover space with the last occurring char. Is there a function to get the last occurring char of a string?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your code to work, without any optimization, you have to compare k to strlen(news) before picking the char in news. It assumes that news has at least one char.

```
void tr_str(char s[], char news[]){
int c;
size_t k =0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        for(k=0; k < strlen(s);k++)
        {                   
            if(c == s[k])
            {
                if (k >= strlen(news))
                    c = news[strlen(news) - 1)];
                else
                    c = news[k];
                break; // Need a break here, else c could be found again in s and translated again.
            }
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Repetiting the last char in news to prevent a repetiting test in the loop is a good idea, but you should not directly modify news[], except if you're sure that in every case news is in a writable large enough memory, and even then it's still bad practice IMO. Make a copy of news and work with it is better.

```
void tr_str(char s[], char news[]){
int c;
size_t k = 0;
size_t sSize = strlen(s);
size_t newsSize = strlen(news);
char *newsCopy;
int preventsMemoryLeak = 0;

    if (newsSize < sSize)
    {
        // Duplicates news in a large enough memory. No need a zero at end of this copy.
        newsCopy = malloc(sSize);
        memcpy(newsCopy, news, newsSize);
        // Fills the remaining with a copy of the last char
        memset(newsCopy + newsSize, news[newsSize - 1], sSize - newsSize);

        preventsMemoryLeak = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        newsCopy = news;
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        for(k = 0; k < sSize; k++)
        {                   
            if(c == s[k])
            {
                c = newsCopy[k];
                break;
            }
        }
        putchar(c);
    }

    if (preventsMemoryLeak == 1) free(newsCopy);
}
```